# Run google script on dialog open

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that would get the URL of an image from the active cell, open up a dialog box and display that image. Through lots of googling and trials and errors I have come up with the code below that displays the image in the dialog box when the user clicks "Read Cell B2" button. Please see the spreadsheet in [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Q2uPJcudw2korCS4AhbiomCnyOZV6CH5dOC6RuQoWE/edit?usp=sharing).

Question: How to avoid the "Read Cell B2 button" so that the image would automatically be loaded when the dialog box opens?

IndexQ.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function onSuccess(B2Value) {
      //document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = B2Value;
      document.getElementById('img2').src = B2Value;
      }
    </script>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Read Cell B2" 
    onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnCellValue('B2')" />
    <br /> 
      Cell B2 contains value: <div id="output"></div> 
    <br />
    <img id="img2" src="" alt="Second Image" height="300">
    <input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onclick="google.script.host.close()" /></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Sidebar').addItem('OpenDialog', 'openDialog').addItem('OpenSidebar', 'openSidebar').addToUi()
}

function returnCellValue(cell) {
 return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getValue();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('IndexQ').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use templated HTML with a scriptlet:

```
<img id="img2" src="<?!= returnCellValue('B2') ?>" alt="Second Image" height="300">
```

[Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

You'll need to modify the code that opens the dialog:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('IndexQ')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setHeight(500);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

Note the `createTemplateFromFile()` and `evaluate()` methods.

or use an `onload` function that runs when the dialog is opened:

```
  <script>
    console.log('it ran!');

    window.onload = function() {//Runs after dialog is loaded
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnCellValue('B2');

    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thank you a lot! The first approach works perfect! I tried to learn/understand the onload part but couldn't get that approach to work. What I tried was I put the window.onload code in openDialogWorks() - did not work, and then I put it in <body> script tag - did not work. Where should I put it?

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer by checking the big green check mark.  Thanks for letting me know that it worked.

Comment: Sandy, could you please explain me how to run the "window.onload" part? I experimented by putting it in one or another file, but it did not work. If I would know how to run it, then maybe I might be able to run this code as well:  window.top.document.getElementsByClassName("script-application-sidebar")[0].styl‌​e.width='300px' "300px"

Comment: I updated the answer to show the `onload` in a script tag.  Put that all the way to the end, but before the last `</html>` tag.  Put a `console.log('it ran!');` statement inside of the `window.onload = function() {`.  I'm guessing that the issue you are having is handling the return back from the server with the `onSuccess()` function.  Put a `console.log('it ran!');` in your success function also.  First thing to know, is what is running and what isn't.  I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. The onload solution is using window class. When I type it in the google scripts window followed by a dot, I don't get the child class pop up options so I wouldn't know that I can enter "onload". How do I know that the window.online code will work or how can I know that it is even there?
2. Would it be possible to execute this code via window.onload:
   `window.top.document.getElementsByClassName("script-application-sidebar")[0].styl‌​e.width='300px' "300px"` ?
   The spreadsheet that I have shared has also OpenSidebar submenu which opens a sidebar. I dropped that approach because I couldn't make the sidebar wide enough to display the image. This script does the job if run from the console. So far I haven't been lucky with finding a solution, but now with this window.onload thing it might be possible?!

Comment: There is no help context for the `window` object in the Apps Script code editor.  The `window` object is part of what is called the DOM.  It's not JavaScript.  Because it is so tightly integrated with JavaScript, people often mistake it for JavaScript.  The DOM (Document Object Model) is a "Web API", meaning that it provides a way to interact between JavaScript and the browser.  jQuery is often used to make that "bridge" between JavaScript and the DOM.  But you don't need jQuery to use DOM methods.  You can use the DOM directly.

Comment: One good resource for the DOM is Mozilla.  [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)